# how to draw a line between two points in osm

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I want to draw a line between two point in osm map

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map();

var start_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,10);
var end_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(30,0);

var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
vector.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([start_point, end_point]))]);
map.addLayers([vector]);
```

I try this code but it did not work so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for drawing linestring is correct. Since you didn't post whole code and exact description of error, only two wild guesses. Your map may be in 900913 projection, and coordinates are in WGS. Transform them:

```
var start_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,10);
var end_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(30,0);

start_point.transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
); 
end_point.transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
);
```

Also, you may need to fit view:

```
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```